# Spring boot JWT Auth details are null

Tags: java, spring-boot, jwt, jhipster

I created Spring boot app using Jhipster. I wanted to create listener that will catch failed authentication.

```
@Component
public class AuthenticationFailureListener
implements ApplicationListener<AuthenticationFailureBadCredentialsEvent> {

@Autowired
private LoginAttemptService loginAttemptService;

public void onApplicationEvent(AuthenticationFailureBadCredentialsEvent e) {
    WebAuthenticationDetails auth = (WebAuthenticationDetails) e.getAuthentication().getDetails();
    if(auth!=null) {
        loginAttemptService.loginFailed(auth.getRemoteAddress());
    }
}
}
```

I am Using JWT. When i debug this method, i can see email and password, but details are null. So auth object is null so i can't see from which IP user tried to login. What should i change in order to get details here ?

Answer (score 0):

I used a similar approach but injected the HttpRequest

```
@Component
public class AuthenticationFailureEventListener implements ApplicationListener<AuthenticationFailureBadCredentialsEvent> {
    private final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(AuthenticationFailureEventListener.class);
    private final HttpServletRequest request;

    private final LoginAttemptService loginAttemptService;

    public AuthenticationFailureEventListener(HttpServletRequest request, LoginAttemptService loginAttemptService) {
        this.request = request;
        this.loginAttemptService = loginAttemptService;
    }

    @Override
    public void onApplicationEvent(final AuthenticationFailureBadCredentialsEvent e) {
        log.debug("Failed login try from {}", request.getRemoteAddr());
        final String xfHeader = request.getHeader("X-Forwarded-For");
        if (xfHeader == null) {
            loginAttemptService.loginFailed(request.getRemoteAddr());
        } else {
            loginAttemptService.loginFailed(xfHeader.split(",")[0]);
        }
    }

}
```

This works really good.